# How to reconfigure a Flash Drive for use with XBox and the PC?

Tags: xbox-360

My XBox 360 flash drive is already configured fully for XBox 360. How do I de-configure it so I can split it for use with the XBox and PC?

I have looked in the storage settings but I can't find anything. It will not de-configure.

Comment: Could you give us a bit more info on what you want to do? I know this can be done if your wanting to share multimedia (videos, music, pictures). Games can not, but then, you can not get a game that will run on both consoles. The base game file needs to be specifically built for its platform. Otherwise, they wouldnt bother going out of their way to package them as PC or Xbox - it would just waste money

Comment: Basically when you plug a new device into my xbox it automatically is configured????? Normally you have the choice of configure now or customise which lets you choose how much gigabytes to use with PC data and how much GB to use with Xbox.So I am asking how do I de-configure my memory stick so I need to configure it again to use it??         Also I know xbox files are different to PC you can't see them on the flash drive on windows.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you can do it on the XBox, but you can do it on the computer.

First, plug the flash drive into your computer, and open My Computer. Right click on the flash drive and click <kbd>format</kbd>. A window will pop up, just click format (don't bother changing settings). Your flash drive is ow formatted.

Please note you cannot use the same flash drive for both XBox 360 and PC simultaneously.

Comment: If on xbox you press Y on the flash drive (in storage) it has an option to format.I have already tried this but not on the pc.

Comment: BIG NOTE: This will ***erase the save games from your flash drive***.

Comment: OMG GOOD POINT! I completely forgot.... sorry if I caused any mishap..